# How can I permanently disable a xinput device?

Tags: xorg, init, xinput

I have a rogue xinput device due to some OS error that sends key press signals even tough nothing is pressed thereby causing screen flickering and the loss of mouse focus.

The device is:

```
xinput list 8
Video Bus                                   id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
This device is disabled
Reporting 1 classes:
    Class originated from: 8. Type: XIKeyClass
    Keycodes supported: 248
```

How can I permanently disable it so it won't come back after restarting the machine?

OS is: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Try to add something like this into your `xorg.conf` or under `xorg.conf.d` folder:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier         "disable broken device"
   MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
   MatchProduct       "full product name from 'xinput list'"
   Option             "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Under Ubuntu, you can find the folder here `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`.

For the change to take effect, you likely need to reboot or at least restart the X server.

[See documentation here.](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml)

Comment: I tried to do it but it doesn't seem to work, this is what i get from xinput list: "xinput -list 8
Video Bus                                id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]
 Reporting 1 classes:
  Class originated from: 8. Type: XIKeyClass
  Keycodes supported: 248"
And this is the content of the file i put at /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-disable.conf:"Section "InputClass"
   Identifier         "disable broken device"
   MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
   MatchProduct       "Video Bus"
   Option             "Ignore" "on"
EndSection"

Comment: One has to put the device name into `Identifier` and not just have some comment there. Then one does not need the `MatchProduct` clause any more.

Comment: @samy I think you had to reboot. It worked perfectly for me. Although I used `Option "Ignore" "true"` since the docs says to use `"true"`. And I used the USB ID option: `MatchUSBID "1aad:000f"`. You can also use glob-like matching characters (i.e. `MatchUSBID "1aad:*"` would make sure that all devices from that one manufacturer are disabled).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an optimal solution but I found a workaround to ensure that the xinput device is disabled for the current user.

I used the `gnome-session-properties` program to simply execute the line `/bin/bash -c "xinput disable 8"` on login. This works only for Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

You create a script to disable it in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/`

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /usr/bin/xinput ] &&
    xinput disable 'Video Bus'
```

The scripts in that directory get run automatically when X11 starts.

I suggest `/bin/sh` because the default scripts in that directory use `sh` over `bash`, probably for portability.

Comment: But this gets reset when you come back from suspend, right?

Comment: @MartinUeding I wouldn't expect X to actively enable new devices from suspend, but I admit I've not tried that.