# Can I make my system ignore a particular gamepad input?

Tags: input, xinput, games

I'm using a Corsair keyboard/touchpad combo which also functions as a gamepad input (it has a small joystick).  It's a bit annoying because it often takes priority, so I have to unplug the keyboard to use my gamepad.

Is there any way to make my system just ignore this particular input as if it is not connected?

Comment: this may or may not help ... https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro/wiki/Methods-for-Disabling-Joystick-Reading-in-Linux

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278333/how-can-i-permanently-disable-a-xinput-device